# How to update datasource when click on cheakbox row in kendo grid view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to know without update button row  change data when checkbox is checked or click on . Kendo grid view have sample code for this , my problem is when get data from datasource in ng-click button not updated datasource

I used the flowing code for ng-click

```
 $scope.saveLayerRole = function () {
        var model = {};
        console.log($("#layerGrid").data().kendoGrid._data);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the Kendo DataSource manually from you button's click, you have to do this :

```
$("#layerGrid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
```